# jQuery custom function losing scope within an each iteration?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write my own modal popup window using a jQuery function. However, I'm having a problem whereby the latest window I create will be the window that is shown by all controls. I'm obviously doing something totally wrong.

Please see the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ff34s/5/

I would of expected the results of the following code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Put the editor in a dialog window
    $("#test1").gttdialog({
    });

    // Put the editor in a dialog window
    $("#test2").gttdialog({
    });

    $("#test1").gttdialog.show();
});
```

...to show the div containing **1**, but instead I get the div containing **2**.

Why is this? I can only guess that the chunk of code where this goes wrong is during the each iteration:

```
    // Create the dialog window
    this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var controls = renderDialog($this);
        hide(controls);

        // Handle the resize event
        $(window).resize(function () {
            keepCentered(controls.dialog);
            maintainMask(controls.mask);
        });

        $this.gttdialog.show = function () {
            show(controls);
        };
        $this.gttdialog.hide = function () {
            hide(controls);
        };
    });
```

Only the latest creation of the variable `controls` seems to be kept in scope.

**UPDATE:**

The problem is due to:

```
$this.gttdialog.show = function () {
    show(controls);
};
$this.gttdialog.hide = function () {
    hide(controls);
};
```

They get reassigned on the 2nd iteration. How can I make this work for all iterations? I'm obviously doing something totally wrong with jQuery functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is

```
 $this.gttdialog.show = function () {
     show(controls);
 };
```

`gttdialog` is a property that is shared by **all** jQuery objects (it refers to `$.fn.gttdialog`). Whenever you call `$("#test2").gttdialog` you are overwriting this property.

So what you'd have to do is to attach the controls to this particular instance. You could do:

```
$this.gttdialogControls = { // you should probably choose a better name ;)
     show: function () {
         show(controls);
     },
     hide: function () {
         hide(controls);
     }
};
```

But then you have to keep a reference to the object, because calling `jQuery` will create a new jQuery object:

```
var d = $("#test1").gttdialog({});
d.gttdialogContols.show();
// won't work:
$("#test1").gttdialogContols.show();
```

Another option would be to work with `.data()`.

**Update:** Considering your code below, I think you can have it much easier. I would store the controls with `.data()`:

```
this.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var controls = renderDialog($this);
    hide(controls);
    //...
    $this.data('gttcontrols', controls);
});
```

and

```
// Add the show and hide functions
$.fn.gttShowDialog = function () {
    return this.each(function() {
        show($(this).data('gttcontrols'));
    });       
};
$.fn.gttHideDialog = function () {
    return this.each(function() {
        hide($(this).data('gttcontrols'));
    });
};
```

Then you don't have to deal with IDs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I've answered with my final solution. Please let me know if there's anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding unique Ids to the controls created by the function:

```
$dialog.attr("id", id + "_Dialog");
$header.attr("id", id + "_Header");
$container.attr("id", id + "_Container");
$mask.attr("id", id + "_Mask");
```

Then I modified the functions that were previously within the each iterator to be global jQuery functions:

```
// Add the show and hide functions
$.fn.gttShowDialog = function () {
    var controls = $.fn.gttdialog._getDialogControls(this[0].id);
    show(controls);
};
$.fn.gttHideDialog = function () {
    var controls = $.fn.gttdialog._getDialogControls(this[0].id);
    hide(controls);
};
```

Then all I needed to do was to retrieve the controls by their unique Ids and pass them to the appropriate method:

```
$.fn.gttdialog._getDialogControls = function (id) {
    var controls = [];
    controls["dialog"] = $("#" + id + "_Dialog");
    controls["header"] = $("#" + id + "_Header");
    controls["container"] = $("#" + id + "_Container");
    controls["mask"] = $("#" + id + "_Mask");
    return controls;
};
```

Now to set up and call, I just do the following:

```
$("#waitElement").gttdialog();
$("#waitElement").gttShowDialog();
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ff34s/6/).